Hola, es la primera vez que hago deploy de una app en vercel, pero no se estan sirviendo los archicos estaticos, como puedo resolverlo
Dejo la estructura de mi proyecto 
El deploy lo esto haciendo en vercel, subo los cambios a github y desde alli se sincroniza con vercel. He leido un poco y veo que la manera de servir los archivos estaticos en desarrollo es diferente de como se deben servir en producción (hablando de Django), adjunto mi configuración de settings.py, urls.py y el archivo vercel.json
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí


Bienvenido. Por favor agrega más información. ¿Qué procedimiento sigues para hacer el deploy? No creo que la estructura de carpetas por sí sola sea de ayuda.

Hola, gracias por responder, modifique la pregunta y adjunte mas información sobre el problema que tengo

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El problema especifico es que al hacer deploy de mi web hecha con django en vercel, no se cargan los archivos estaticos, por lo cual mi pagina se ve sin estilos
